# Mockitio - returning null when expecting mock in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a method in a class called `FruitBasket` which I would like to test as so:

```
// Method to test
public Fruit getFruit(String fruitName) {
    Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

    if(fruitExists(fruitName)) {
        fruit = getFruitByName(fruitName);
    }
    else {
        fruit.setFruitName(fruitName);
        saveFruit(fruit);
        fruit = getFruitByName(fruitName);
    }

    return fruit;
}



private Fruit getFruitByName(String fruitName) {
    return fruitDao.getFruitByName(fruitName);
}

public boolean fruitExists(String fruitName) {
    return fruitDao.fruitExists(fruitName);
}
```

I have written a unit test for this method as follows:

```
@Mock
FruitDao fruitDao;
@Mock
Fruit mockFruit;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testgetFruitMethod() {
    FruitBasket fruitBasket = new FruitBasket (fruitDao);
    Fruit apple = fruitBasket.getFruit("Apple");

    when(fruitDao.fruitExists(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
    when(fruitDao.getFruitByName(anyString())).thenReturn(mockFruit);

    assertThat(apple, instanceOf(Fruit.class));
}
```

However the test fails with an assertion error. An instance of Fruit was expected but null was returned instead.

Can anyone spot an issue to why I am getting null?

Comment: How is `apple` going to be affected by your `when` statements?

Comment: What does the constructor of `FruitBasket` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `fruitBasket.getFruit("Apple");` results in invocations of `FruitDao` which has not been configured yet so as to know what invocations to expect and how to respond to them.  I suppose mockito's default behavior when it has no clue what to do is to just return null instead of throwing an exception, so your mocked `FruitDao` returns a null `Fruit`, and your test blows up.

So, you need to first do your `when()`s and then invoke `Fruit apple = fruitBasket.getFruit("Apple");`

Comment: "I suppose mockito's default behavior when it has no clue what to do is to just return null" <-- your supposition is correct, but more precisely, Mockito just uses the default values specified by the JLS when you don't provide any; and the default value for any `Object` is `null` (and 0 for numeric primitives, and `false` for booleans)

Comment: Thanks for this! I can't believe I made this mistake, I have unit tests elsewhere in my code base where the `when()` statements are correctly positioned. Just a silly error on my part which I overlooked!

Comment: Don't worry about it; it happens even to the best of us.

Answer (score 2):

Try to prepare mock before use it:

```
@Test
public void testgetFruitMethod() {
    // given
    when(fruitDao.fruitExists(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
    when(fruitDao.getFruitByName(anyString())).thenReturn(mockFruit);
    FruitBasket fruitBasket = new FruitBasket (fruitDao);

    // when
    Fruit apple = fruitBasket.getFruit("Apple"); 

    // then 
    assertThat(apple, instanceOf(Fruit.class));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I would also accept this as the correct answer but the other answer posted is also correct and was posted seconds before yours.